# Hibernate: Trouble using sessionFactory.getTypeHelper().custom(userType)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Hibernate.custom(userType) is gone in Hibernate 5.2.10.Final so I have to use sessionFactory.getTypeHelper().custom(userType). Is there any way to get TypeHelper without sessionFactory? Previously I was using hibernate 3.6.10.Final. I would rather not use sessionFactory but I can't really find a way around it.

The main goal is to take a org.hibernate.usertype.UserType and return a org.hibernate.type.Type.

I have this function in 3.6.10.Final

```
public Type getHibernateType() {
    // Type is class that implements hibernates UserType
    return Hibernate.custom(UserType) 
}
```

in 5.2.10.Final I had to change it to something like

```
public Type getHibernateType() {
    return sessionFactory.getTypeHelper().custom(UserType);
}
```

I don't really want to use sessionFactory if I can help it. So I was wondering if there was another way to get the Type.

Comment: suppose you share some code and explain more about your issue.

Comment: I put some of the code in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically 5.2 still exposes the functionality via `TypeFactory` in a static method.

```
Type type = TypeFactory.custom( UserType.class, null, null );
```

However, be aware this method is marked `@Deprecated` and in fact, that entire class has been removed as a part of Hibernate 6.0's type system overhaul.

I would get used to the notion of using the `SessionFactory` to access this information because that is precisely how we have designed 6.0 to work at present.

Comment: I was wondering If I were to do something like
Type type = TypeFactory.custom(EnumType.class, properties, null);

why doesn't the EnumType.class work? Does it have to be a UserType.class?

Comment: Regarding "that is precisely how we have designed 6.0" this plan seemed to have changed since there is no `getTypeHelper` anymore. Care to shed some light on the current plan? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71601352/how-to-create-a-typedparametervalue-in-hibernate-6