# How to create a TypedParameterValue in Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-6.x

With Hibernate 5.x we used code similar to the following in order to create a `TypedParameterValue`

```java
Class<?> someType = //
Session session = //
TypeHelper typeHelper = session.getSessionFactory().getTypeHelper();
Type type = typeHelper.basic(someType);
return new TypedParameterValue(type, null);
```

With Hibernate 6 `getTypeHelper` is gone from the `SessionFactory`.

What is the appropriate way to get a `TypedParameterValue` with Hibernate 6?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43748487/hibernate-trouble-using-sessionfactory-gettypehelper-customusertype) suggests that the `getTypeHelper` route is the intended one for Hibernate 6, which is "funny" since it doesn't exist any more.

Comment: Perhaps if you could explain what you want to use the `Type` object for? Because it's just not usually needed in Hibernate 6.

Comment: @Tim If I remember correctly: no.

Comment: @GavinKing in my case, it's in order to pass to `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.Expressions.booleanTemplate()` to ensure the correct SQL type literal is used. Presumably there's another way to do that now?

Comment: With Hibernate 6's new type support, it now works for me when passing the object directly. There is no need for `TypedParameterValue` in my specific case.